# Kotlin: I am unable to hold previous value of a function when calling it multiple times

Tags: kotlin, multidimensional-array

I need to show different seat arrangement till the user is making choices and register it's previous choices as well in the displayed seat arrangement.
My code is:

```
package cinema

fun main() {
    println("Enter the number of rows:")
   val row = readLine()!!.toInt()
   
   println("Enter the number of seats in each row")
   val seats = readLine()!!.toInt()
   var price = 0
   
   
   val totalSeats = row*seats
   var rowNumberUpdate = 0
   var seatNumberUpdate = 0
   var a = true
   
    fun seatDisplay(){
           var newSeatCount = 1
           println("Cinema: ")
                print(" ")
        
                while(newSeatCount <=seats){
            
                    print(" $newSeatCount")
                    newSeatCount += 1
                }
        
                print("\n")
                for(i in 1..row){
        
                    print(i)
        
                    for(j in 1..seats){
                        if(i == rowNumberUpdate && j==seatNumberUpdate) print(" B") else print(" S") 
           
           
                    }
                    println()
                }
       }
   
    fun priceDisplay(){
           println("Enter a row number: ")
                 val rowNumber = readln().toInt()
                 rowNumberUpdate = rowNumber
                 println("Enter a seat number in that row: ")
                 val seatNumber = readln().toInt()
                 seatNumberUpdate = seatNumber
   
                 if(totalSeats<=60){
                     price = 10
                 } else {
                       if(row%2==0){
                           if(rowNumber<=row/2) price = 10 else price = 8
                        } else {
                              if(rowNumber<=row/2) price = 10 else price = 8
                          }
                    }
                println("Ticket price: $$price")
       }
       
       
   
       
   
   
   while(a){
       println("1. Show the seats")
       println("2. Buy a ticket")
       println("0. Exit")
       val optionsInput = readln().toInt()
       
       when(optionsInput){
            1 -> seatDisplay()
   
            2 -> priceDisplay()
   
            0 -> a = false

       }
   }
       
}
```

Problem with this code is, everytime user is making choice it is showing the seat arrangement as per the latest choice. It doesn't hold the value of previous choices.

You can see this in output attached as an [image]image. Please zoom the image for clear visibility.

Hoping to get some help from the community.

Comment: Please provide the output in form of text instead of an image.

Comment: Also, that looks like far more code than necessary to demonstrate the issue.  Please try to reduce it to a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the selection of the user in variables `rowNumberUpdate` and `seatNumberUpdate` that can hold singular values. If you intend to memorize all choices, you have to change these variables to be some kind of collection (e.g. a list) and add every choice to that collection:

```
val seatUpdate = mutableListOf<Pair<Int, Int>>()
```

and in `seatDisplay`:

```
if(seatUpdate.contains(Pair(i,j))) print(" B") else print(" S")
```

and in `priceDisplay`:

```
seatUpdate.add(Pair(rowNumber, seatNumber))
```

Comment: Yeah, it worked! But why it wasn't working when I was storing the value of row and column in variable and checking accordingly in loop everytime? I was updating the variables as well according to the input in priceDisplay. Can you suggest me any article to read to understand the difference or anything you want to let me know will be helpful.